# How to check Alamofire failure of bad internet connection?

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, alamofire, response

How can i check if my Alamofire request Failed because of bad internet connection? I get an error but how can i know that it failed because of that

> Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, NSUnderlyingError=0x6000007fe6a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey={length = 28, capacity = 28, bytes = 0x1c1e1f96000000000000000000000000 ... 0000000100000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-4, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalUploadTask .<1>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
>       "LocalUploadTask .<1>"
>   )

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: check question again

Comment: for handling it :
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1941/_index.html
else only to find you are getting error code `NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 `

Answer (score 1):

You can get the error message from the failure case like this

```
Alamofire.request("YourURL", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { response in
    if case .failure(let error) = response.result {
        print(error.localizedDescription)//The network connection was lost.
    } else if case .success = response.result {
        print(response.result.value)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the failure reason through the `underlyingError` property from `AFError` as follows

```
Alamofire.request("url", method: .post, parameters: parameters)
.responseJSON { response in
  if let afError = response.error,
  let underlyingError = afError.underlyingError as? URLError {
    switch underlyingError.code {
    case URLError.notConnectedToInternet:
        // do your thing here
    default:
        // any other URLError code handling
  }
}
```